# Getting inputs from txt file and add in an array

Tags: c, file

I am newer in C language. I want to create an array for my code to make some operation. As I said above, I am trying to learn how to use C language efficiently. My problem is this: I have a input file, let's say input.txt. I know that every line have 4 different things, 2 of them are string and 2 of them number. Also, I want to create a 2D array. But I do not know how many lines will be in input file. It depends on the user. So, I have to use **malloc** to make my array dynamically. So, can you help me about this problem? Maybe this is so easy, but I think reading file and create some array in C more difficult than other languages. It was so easy in Python :( I am leaving my code below. If you tell me my mistakes, I will be happy :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char *arrChar;
    int i;
    char *str;
    char *token;
    arrChar = (char *) malloc( sizeof( char ) );
    str = (char *) malloc( sizeof( char ) );
    FILE *FileChars;
    FileChars = fopen( argv[1], "r");
    i = 0;
    while ( fgets(str, sizeof str, FileChars) != NULL) {
        int j;
        for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++ ) {
                token = strtok(str, ",");
                arrChar[i][j] = token;
            }
        i++;
         }
}
```

Comment: You have allocate for one `char` variable. And then tried to access a single level pointer using subscript operator twice. Undefined behavior you have when using `fgets` - because you allow it to write to memory that you don't have. Use of `strtok` is wrong.

Comment: The most important issue you have appears to be the `sizeof` operator. Also, in [tag:c] you don't need to cast `malloc()`'s return value like that.

Comment: And you should also, check that `FileChars` is not `NULL` after `fopen()`, if you give a wrong path, or your user don't have access to it then *undefined behavior* will occur when reading with `fgets()`. It already occurs becuse `sizeof str` is not what you think.

Comment: Also, read [`strtok()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html)'s manual page, you have to pass `NULL` for subsequent tokens.

Comment: *It was so easy in Python* - some languages are friendly for string processing. C is one of the worst in terms of user friendliness, the amount of code you need to write, and also safety, but is also one of the fastest.

Comment: See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Don't you have any sample code? Because, I can understand what you mean better if I see sample code.

Comment: @fokclac Read my answer, there is "*sample code*" in it, commented so that you reall understand why every fix.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Yes, I have seen your code just after my above post :) Thank you so much, I am going to look at it and try to understand :)

Comment: @fokclac What warning/error did your compiler give with `arrChar[i][j] = token;`.  If none, what compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to understand precisely what the `sizeof` operator does, it doesn't return the size of a dynamically allocated memory block, it returns the size of a type, in case of arrays — *roughly speaking* — the size is part of the type specification and so it returns the number of bytes the array occupies.

   In your case `sizeof(char)` is the size of the type `char` which is required to be exactl *1* by the ([c-standard](/questions/tagged/c-standard) *C Standard*).

   And `sizeof(str)` is the size of the type of `str` which is `char *`, that is, the size of a pointer. It's probably `4` or `8` depending on your current platform.

   To solve this, you have to define a length to be used throughout your program as the length of the allocated chunk of memory, that after you make sure that the allocation was successful (*see below*).
2. A pointer to `char` can point to a sequence of elements that can be interpreted as a string if it is the correct sequence. A sequence of "*printable*" characters followed by a `'\0'` or *null* character is considered a string.
3. You have to pass `NULL` to `strtok()` after the first time, if you are going to be processing the same string.
4. You should CHECK that `fopen()` did return a valid stream, by comparing the return value to `NULL`.
5. The same as (5), for `malloc()` when allocation is not possible `NULL` is returned and using it as a valid pointer is *undefined behavior*.

All that said, here is what you probably wanted to write

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_WORDS 100

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *token;
    char **words;
    char line[100];
    char *ptr;
    size_t count;
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen( argv[1], "r");
    // Check that we DID open the file
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Allocate space for `NUM_WORDS' pointers
    words = malloc(NUM_WORDS * sizeof(*words));
    // Check that we did allocate enough memory
    if (words == NULL) {
        fclose(file);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // We use `sizeof' here because `line' is an array
    count = 0;
    while ((count < NUM_WORDS) && (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)) {
        ptr = line;
        do {
            token = strtok(ptr, ",");
            // We need to copy the `token' because
            // it lies within `line' and the '\0' will
            // be replaced by the original character
            // in subsequent callse to `strtok()'
            //
            // The `strdup()' will allocate enough space with
            // `malloc()' then copy the contents of `token' to the
            // allocated buffer, and return it, so we will
            // have to call `free()' on every `words' element.
            words[count++] = strdup(token);
            // Subsequent calls to `strtok()' with the same
            // string require that the first parameter is
            // NULL
            ptr = NULL;
         } while ((count < NUM_WORDS) && (token != NULL));
    }
    // Now we may print the words and free the memory
    for (size_t index = 0; index < count; ++index) {
        puts(words[index]);
        free(words[index]);
    }
    free(words);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the code above, makes sure that we don't exceed the capacity of the array of pointers `words`<sup>1</sup>. If you need to resize it, you will need to learn how to use `realloc()` and do it in a specialized routine so that your code doesn't become too complex.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that the allocated space has no predefined interpretation, we do interpret it as an array but it's not an array in the [c](/questions/tagged/c) sense of an array definition, which `line` IS, having elements of type `char`, line can also be interpreted as a string given it has contents compatible with the defintion given in the (2) second point above.